# What are the latex and dvips path in jaxodraw preferences?

Tags: texlive, texmaker, feynman

I am using "jaxodraw-2.1-0.jar" and the "axodraw4j.sty" file is inside the directory where I am drawing and keeping my diagrams. Whenever I try to export the diagram it shows "Cannot execute command! Please try 'export LaTeX' and run latex manually." so I did. I ran the generated latex code using my "texmaker". First I used "pdflatex" and it generated a blank figure with just the latex labels but no arrows or anything ! Then I read somewhere that I must do "Latex->Dvips->Ps2Pdf-" etc so I configured my "quickbuild" tab in texmaker that way and executed which showed the following error

---

Process started

warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015:/usr/local/texlive/2015/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf/web2c. This is dvips(k) 5.995 Copyright 2015 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) dvips: ! Couldn't find header file: tex.pro

Process exited with error(s)

---

So I came back to jaxodraw and opened "preferences", I saw that the two fields: latex path and dvips path are empty. I wrote latex in the latex path and dvips in the dvips path because I don't know what else to do.. I have no idea what is the exact path for them ! Then I tried to export again using the default "LaTeX->EPS" it showed another error: "Error:_Executionof_dvips_failed!"  I think if I could specify the right paths for latex and dvips it will export correctly and will directly generate the EPS file.. because I remember I used jaxodraw in another computer with ubuntu many months ago and that was generating the EPS directly and seamlessly ! But I don't know what are the paths.

Additional info:

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and it's Lubuntu. 
I have installed Texlive Vanilla following the instructions given here: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Any help will be highly appreciated because I am really stuck.

PS: If I choose just "EPS" instead of "LaTeX->EPS" it produces the diagrams without any latex labels, so again useless.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that your TeXLive installation is corrupted or incomplete.  It shows that the programs `latex` and `dvips` were indeed run, but that the files `texmf.cnf` and `tex.pro` are missing, even though they are essential to the functioning of these programs.  They should have been created by a standard install of TeXLive 2015 in the following locations:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro
```

I would recommend reinstalling TeXLive (of which the current version when I wrote this answer is TeXLive 2016). I'd recommend you to make this a full installation, and take the default options.

After that `latex` and `dvips` should work.

Once you have a correctly functioning TeXLive installation, `jaxodraw`'s export to `eps` should work with `jaxodraw`'s default settings for the paths to `latex` and `dvips`, which are just the strings 'latex' and 'dvips'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did work after installing the new version (2016 and up[stream) of the texlive, although there seems to be another problem not related to jaxodraw. This has to do with the "PATH" problem of latex itself. I can't update anything using tlmgr and even after deleting Texlive 2015, the pdflatex seems to be using the old version mysteriously. Here's a link to the question that I have created:     http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325364/tlmgr-update-self-all-wont-work-even-after-a-fresh-installation-of-texlive

Comment: Update: after trying everything to solve the texlive version conflicts, in the end I completely **purged** all the versions of Texlive and anything related then followed [this excellent answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373) step by step, everything seems now working perfectly.