# "tlmgr update --self/all" won't work even after a fresh installation of Texlive 2016

Tags: texlive, texmaker, paths, update

I was unable to update Texlive 2015 using tlmgr so I installed the latest version, that is 2016 following the [instructions](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). After the installation of 2016 I removed the old (2015) version and set the path to

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

I also compiled a lot of tex files without any errors and also the installation log file (of 2016) showed no signs of errors. Then I tried to check if the update command (`tlmgr update --self`
) works, it didn't ! The error message was:

```
All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater............................................................................................................................................................................
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

Can anyone please help me understand what needs to be done, for example:  I don't understand why is it still asking for a "PATH" given the fact that I have already set it up typing the following line in the terminal:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

Out of curiosity I then repeated the update command by specifying the whole path, that is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self
```

And it worked, because the output was:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available.
```

So I tried to update the packages instead by using:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all
```

which also worked and returned:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet 
(verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
[ 1/20, ??:??/??:??] update: europasscv [378k] (41201 -> 41866) ... done
[ 2/20, 00:05/04:04] update: glossaries-extra [3355k] (41486 -> 41856) ... done
[ 3/20, 00:09/00:44] update: latexpand [8k] (37592 -> 41873) ... done
[ 4/20, 00:10/00:49] update: markdown [333k] (41376 -> 41855) ... done
[ 5/20, 00:12/00:54] update: mweights [3k] (31268 -> 41867) ... done
[ 6/20, 00:16/01:12] update: newpx [1707k] (39698 -> 41863) ... done
[ 7/20, 00:22/01:10] update: newtx [4028k] (40165 -> 41864) ... done
[ 8/20, 00:27/00:50] update: parnotes [129k] (41775 -> 41868) ... done
[ 9/20, 00:29/00:53] update: texlive-docindex [220k] (41843 -> 41862) ... done
[10/20, 00:31/00:56] update: udesoftec [618k] (40613 -> 41872) ... done
[11/20, 00:32/00:54] auto-install: cormorantgaramond (41865) [5284k] ... done
[12/20, 00:37/00:42] auto-install: phffullpagefigure (41857) [250k] ... done
[13/20, 00:38/00:42] auto-install: phfnote (41858) [667k] ... done
[14/20, 00:39/00:42] auto-install: phfparen (41859) [311k] ... done
[15/20, 00:40/00:42] auto-install: phfqit (41860) [343k] ... done
[16/20, 00:40/00:41] auto-install: phfquotetext (41869) [201k] ... done
[17/20, 00:41/00:42] auto-install: phfsvnwatermark (41870) [208k] ... done
[18/20, 00:42/00:42] auto-install: phfthm (41871) [397k] ... done
[19/20, 00:43/00:43] update: collection-fontsextra [2k] (41736 -> 41865) ... done
[20/20, 00:44/00:44] update: collection-latexextra [6k] (41853 -> 41871) ... done
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
```

I would like to know how can I really solve this "PATH" problem. I can specify the whole path each time but I really don't want to.

Some other information that I would like to provide are:

which tex

returns  `/usr/bin/tex`

Similarly `which latex` and `which pdflatex` etc return `/usr/bin/latex` and `/usr/bin/pdflatex`

So clearly the path specification didn't work!

---

**Forgot to add the log file of a tex compilation which I think is important**

The log file was too big so I decided to save it as a "google do" and provide the [link here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1am668ZVtPX7bu78VwaUey7r4FLngN4g9HWva0d2gDMc/edit?usp=sharing).
I am pasting the first line though:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.23)
```

Does it say I am still using texlive 2015? I don't know how is that even possible because I have erased the whole directory `/usr/local/texlive/2015`  there's only one directory/file inside `/usr/local/texlive` and that is `2016`.

Comment: Did you just write `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` in a terminal? I usually put this information in my `.profile` (which you must `source` if you're still in the same terminal 'session').

Comment: Your commands use the TeXLive distribution installed by your OS (Debian, Ubuntu or any variant). You may change your `.profile` to add the correct PATH (just for you). You may change the PATH in `/etc/environment` to add the correct PATH (for all users).

Comment: You may read section 3.4 (3.4.1 and 3.4.2) from the [TeX Live Guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-300003.4)...

Comment: You may want to read http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/texlive-YEAR-ubuntu.pdf (change the year into 2016, of course). You can skip much of the procedure, go where `/opt/texbin` is defined and where the PATH environment variable is dealt with.

Comment: When adding code (or a log) in a question/answer, paste it, select it and click the `{}` button above the editing window.

Comment: @John, yes I typed that in the terminal just after installing the upstream texlive.  Paul Gaborit, pardon me but can you please explain your first comment ("...Your commands use the TeXLive distribution installed by your OS ...") a bit because I am not an expert and about your next comment referring to [link](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-300003.4) I will read it and will update you. egreg I will follow that and will be back. and I didn't know how to handle the code well now I do.. thanks.

Comment: @Paul Gaborit, my `/etc/environment` has the following line `PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/texbin"`  What should I change ?

Comment: @Paul Gaborit, I followed the instructions of sec. 3.4.1 of [link](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-300003.4) and now none of my commands work ! To follow the next section "3.4.2" of the link, I tried to `locate` the file `/etc/manpath.config` using:  `locate *manpath.cofig* ` and the error message shows: `Command 'locate' is available in '/usr/bin/locate'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
locate: command not found`   and then I realized that any command returns the same error message ! Help !

Comment: Good news everyone: I was so frustrated that I purged everything related to latex and then followed this brilliant [answer] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373) step by step and everything seems to be fine for now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by reinstallation.

Comment: @TeXnician so if something gets solved it becomes off-topic ? I don't know how this works ! Please help.

Comment: Don't worry. Off-topic is just the category to close a question which was solved without a full-written answer, but is no real duplicate. It just means that you do not really need an answer anymore as you found a solution.